# Accessing current route parameters laravel4

Tags: php, laravel

I can access current route via `Route::currentRouteName()` but do I have any chance to access current route parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameters();
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I want!